# Table DataPlex not supported by Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-dataplex

Currently I created a data lake in dataplex with its zone, within it I generated the asset and the tables are reflected, now when I look for it and access a table it tells me that it is not compatible with bigquery and it does not show me the link to access it to the big query console of said table, any idea why this could be?

I already gave data reader permissions to the user who has to access, even though I was in the same group of GCP users, I tried several things but I don't know why it keeps appearing that it's not compatible, I don't know if it's some configuration.

Attached the image:

[image]